# Program ignoring folder it's in

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have placed my program within a subfolder on the server: localhost/program and when the program runs it runs correctly however all action links and images point to localhost/... rather than localhost/program/...?

I have tried to change my routing by adding "program/" to the beginning of "{controller}/.." however this seems to have little effect? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`Url.Content`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to solve a url for any file or resource on your site. The parameter passed is the relative path prefixed with a tidle (~):

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/image/logo.jpg")"/>
```

The result would be (based on your setup):

```
<img src="http://localhost/program/image/logo.jpg"/>
```

A relative virtual path is relative to the application root directory, if it is just a tilde (~) or starts with the tilde and a double backslash (~\\) or the tilde and a slash mark (~/).